# How does Wunderlist show you what people are typing as they type it?

Tags: rest, model-view-controller, wunderlist

How does a web app like Wunderlist show me what *another person* is typing as they're typing it? I'm assuming it has some kind of js MVC framework on the client side and a REST API server-side, but are each of my colleague's keystrokes being sent to the server as they type? Wouldn't that be intensive on the server? Or is it some other kind of magic I don't know about?

Comment: probably web sockets. See e.g. http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: Thanks for the reply @zapl ! Do you know why a shared hosting provider like Hostgator might block listening sockets on the server side? Is it to avoid ports being tied up? Or for security reasons?

Comment: websockets & persistent connections pose problems with loadbalancing multiple instances, might be that, but idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are right about the way it could work, but i don't see why it would be so intensive on the server. It's nothing more than intercepting keystrokes of arrows for an online game and moving a character accordingly... And servers support much more than this kind of thing.
The amount of information sent is minimal.

Comment: I guess compared to a game it would seem pretty trivial. Would the frequency with which the data is sent be an issue on something like a shared server?

Comment: It depends on the number of users on the website i guess. Anyway it must not be too high or the servers would have to be upgraded anyway. Also, you could refresh the input with a timer instead of sending each keystroke and that would lessen the impact.

Comment: Ohhh right and then just send the new data from the client model. Cool, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Yup ! If you want to make it more realistic you can write letter by letter on the reciever screen even tho the server receives multiple keystrokes at a time ! :) Good luck for making this up if you're gonna implement it on your webservice.